StructuredTool._run() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'config'
I have been tinkering around crewai's web scraping tool called ScrapeWebsiteTool. What I wanted to do was to scrape data from multiple links instead of one.
I was able to make this function possible but maybe it's just doing too much since the tool can only scrape one site at a time?
I just need some insights on this code on how I can solve the error unless there are better methods to tackling my needs.
Code:
from crewai import Agent, Task, Crew
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from crewai_tools import ScrapeWebsiteTool
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_KEY')
Model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo'
llm = ChatOpenAI(model=Model,api_key=api_key)

# Define a list of URLs to scrape (or load them from a file as needed)
urls = [
    'https://www.ibm.com/topics/artificial-intelligence',
    'https://www.ibm.com/topics/machine-learning'
]

# Instantiate tools
web_scrape_tool = ScrapeWebsiteTool()  # No need to specify URL initially


# Create agents (remains the same)
web_scraper_agent = Agent(
    role='Web Scraper',
    goal='Effectively Scrape data on the websites for your company',
    backstory='''You are expert web scraper, your job is to scrape all the data for 
                your company from a given website.
             ''',
    tools=[web_scrape_tool],
    verbose=True,
    llm = llm
)

def sanitize_filename(url):
    invalid_chars = ':/?<>\\|*\"'
    for char in invalid_chars:
        url = url.replace(char, "_")
    return url

# Inside the loop, sanitize the URL before using it as part of the filename
for url in urls:
    # Assuming the tool requires a config dict that includes the website_url
    config = {'website_url': f'{url}'}  # Construct the config with the required website_url

    sanitized_url = sanitize_filename(url)  # Sanitize the URL

    web_scraper_task = Task(
        description=f'Scrape data from {url}',
        expected_output='Content from the website',
        agent=web_scraper_agent,
        output_file=f'data_{sanitized_url}.txt',  # Use sanitized URL for filename
        config=config  # Include the config when setting up the task
    )

    crew = Crew(
        agents=[web_scraper_agent],
        tasks=[web_scraper_task],
        verbose=2
    )

# Execute tasks for all URLs
result = crew.kickoff()
print(result)

with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(result)

Error:
> Entering new CrewAgentExecutor chain...
I need to read the content from the website https://www.ibm.com/topics/machine-learning to scrape the data for my company.

Action: Read website content
Action Input: {'website_url': 'https://www.ibm.com/topics/machine-learning'} 

I encountered an error while trying to use the tool. This was the error: StructuredTool._run() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'config'.
 Tool Read website content accepts these inputs: Read website content(website_url: 'string') - A tool that can be used to read a website content.

Thought: I need to read the content from the website https://www.ibm.com/topics/machine-learning to scrape the data for my company.

Action: Read website content
Action Input: {'website_url': 'https://www.ibm.com/topics/machine-learning'} 

I encountered an error while trying to use the tool. This was the error: StructuredTool._run() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'config'.
 Tool Read website content accepts these inputs: Read website content(website_url: 'string') - A tool that can be used to read a website content.

As you can see, this error executes a few more times on the same website. Not sure why as well and it'd be helpful if you can give some thoughts on this as well.
I already added this 'config' as well since it was asking for it in the error.

are you getting an error stack with line numbers?  if so, please edit your post and add it to the question.

@LhasaDad there were no line error shown in the terminal, it came from the Debug output from crew ai: > Finished chain.
[2024-07-13 14:11:11][DEBUG]: == [Web Scraper] Task output: Unfortunately, since the Read website content tool is not functioning properly, I am unable to retrieve the content from the website https://www.ibm.com/topics/machine-learning.

FYI,  Your kickoff call is not within the loop where you are setting up each of the URL's so only the last one is likely to 'kickoff'

Also,  my best advice is to get this loaded in VS Code and debug it by single stepping through the file and watch for when the error message comes out.   once you know what line causes the error,  then let the debugger enter that code and continue stepping through to see the line in the crewAI code causing the problem.   These should give you a better idea what is being called incorrectly and what is missing.   Sorry I don't have an OpenAI key to try this with or I might be able to do it myself and give you some feedback.

I encountered the same issue after upgrading my crewAI version. Knowing your current crewAI version might provide more insight into the problem. However, assuming you are using one of the latest versions, this information should still be relevant.
As lirockyzhang stated in this thread, the issue is likely due to a  change in Lanchain-core library, specifically that config became required parameter for _run(). The thread also contains links to relevant PRs in Langchain.
What helped me resolve the issue was downgrading the following versions, as suggested by 1WorldCapture:

langchain-core to 0.2.15


langchain to 0.2.6


langchain-community to 0.2.6

